# Port JS crypto code for hash HMAC SHA256 to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I want to port the following JS code:

```
crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
  .update(s)
  .digest('base64');
```

To PHP. How do I do this?

The closest I got was the following:

```
hash_hmac('sha256', $s, $secret)
```

or

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $s, $secret));
```

But neither returns the same result as the JS version.

How do I port the JS to PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to answer my own question:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $s, $secret, true));
```

The last parameter is `raw_output`, which according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php):

> When set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data. FALSE outputs lowercase hexits.

Better solutions are welcome.